# Dummy variable "switch-point" in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a dummy variable that serves as a flag for a number of conditions in my data set. **I can't figure out how to write a function that marks the spot in which the flag assumes a "final switch" -- a value that will not change for the rest of the data frame.** *In the example below, everything after the 7th observation is a "y".*

```
  dplyr::tibble(
    observation = c(seq(1,10)),
    crop = c(runif(3,1,25),
              runif(1,50,100),
              runif(2,1,10),
              runif(4,50,100)),
    flag = c(rep("n", 3),
             rep("y", 1),
             rep("n", 2),
             rep("y", 4)))
```

Which yields:

```
   observation  crop flag 
         <int> <dbl> <chr>
 1           1 13.3  n    
 2           2  4.34 n    
 3           3 17.1  n    
 4           4 80.5  y    
 5           5  9.62 n    
 6           6  8.39 n    
 7           7 92.6  y    
 8           8 74.1  y    
 9           9 95.3  y    
10          10 69.9  y
```

I've tried creating a second flag that marks every switch and returns the "final" switch/flag variable, but over my whole data frame that will likely be highly inefficient. Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this may be to create a flag that cumulatively sums occurrences of flag switches.

```
cumsum_na <- function(x){
  x[which(is.na(x))] <- 0
  return(cumsum(x))
}

df <- dplyr::tibble(
    observation = c(seq(1,10)),
    crop = c(runif(3,1,25),
              runif(1,50,100),
              runif(2,1,10),
              runif(4,50,100)),
    flag = c(rep("n", 3),
             rep("y", 1),
             rep("n", 2),
             rep("y", 4)))

df %>%
  mutate(flag2 = ifelse(flag != lag(flag), 1, 0) %>%
               cumsum_na)

# A tibble: 10 x 4
   observation  crop flag  flag2
         <int> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1           1 12.1  n         0
 2           2 11.2  n         0
 3           3  4.66 n         0
 4           4 61.6  y         1
 5           5  6.00 n         2
 6           6  9.54 n         2
 7           7 67.6  y         3
 8           8 86.7  y         3
 9           9 91.6  y         3
10          10 84.5  y         3
```

You can then do whatever you need to using the `flag2` column (eg. filter for max value, take first row, which will give you the first occurrence of constant state).

Comment: By constant, I mean never to switch again for the rest of the data frame/observations. Will clarify that in original question.

Comment: I edited my answer; let me know if this doesn't solve your problem!

Comment: Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

i count all the "n" first, and when when the final "n" is met, i get the index of the next obs

```
i=0
j=1
while (i<table(df$flag)["n"]) {
  if (as.character(df[j,3]) =="n" ) {
    i=i+1
    j=j+1
  } else j=j+1
}
```

You are looking for j

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, flag2 := rleid(flag)]
df
#    observation      crop flag flag2
# 1:           1 21.472985    n     1
# 2:           2 21.563190    n     1
# 3:           3  1.393184    n     1
# 4:           4 88.422562    y     2
# 5:           5  6.383627    n     3
# 6:           6  8.484030    n     3
# 7:           7 86.998953    y     4
# 8:           8 62.220592    y     4
# 9:           9 93.141503    y     4
#10:          10 96.006885    y     4
```

Comment: rleid seems useful. I'm trying to keep most of my operations in tibbles/dplyr, but I appreciate you offering this answer. Good to know about.

Comment: @BSHuniversity. No problem,  You can just change the syntax to `df %>% mutate(flag2 = rleid(flag))`